Subgroup of index $p$ in a nonabelian finite simple group has $p$ conjugates
Let $G$ be a nonabelian, finite simple group and let $H$ be a subgroup of index $p$, where $p$ is a prime. Prove that the number of distinct conjugates of $H$ in $G$ is $p$.
Here's my attempt. As $|G:H| = p$, the number of left cosets of $H$ is $p$. Let $G$ act on the set of cosets by conjugation. This induces a homomorphism $\varphi:G \to S_p$. Now, $\ker \varphi = 1$ or $G$ by simplicity. Clearly, $\ker \varphi \neq G$ so $\ker \varphi = 1$ and so
$$G / \{1\} \cong G \cong \varphi(G) \leq S_p$$
If $p=2$, then $S_p=S_2$ and this group has no nonabelian simple subgroups. Similarly, for $S_3$ has non nonabelian simple subgroups. Thus, $p \geq 5$. Now, as $G$ is simple, so is $\varphi(G)$. Thus, we must find simple (nonabelian) subgroups of $S_p$. As $p \geq 5$, I'm tempted to say that $\varphi(G) = A_p$ but it's not clear to me that the only simple subgroup of $S_p$ is $A_p$ for $p \geq 5$.
Further, once I establish whether or not $\varphi(G)$ is equal to $A_p$, it's not clear to me how I can proceed from here.
Any thoughts?

is "$p$m" a typo for $p$?

Your title is mis phrased. The subject is "nonabelian simple group., so "has" refers to the group... but is supposed to refer to the subgroup. Fixed it for yo7.

@ArturoMagidin yes it is a typo. I fixed both the typo in $p$ and the title as well

Your change to the title, which I had fixed, again messed it up.

You asked this before!

The number of conjugates equals the index of the normalizer. The normalizer contains $H$, and since the index of $H$ is prime, either $H=N_G(H)$, or $N_G(H)=G$. The latter implies $H$ is normal, hence trivial (as $G$ is simple), but then $G$ would have order $p$, contradicting non-abelianicity. So $H=N_G(H)$, the normalizer has index $p$, so $H$ has $p$ conjugates.
Note we do not need to assume $G$ is finite.

Thank you! Is there a book where the statement "the number of conjugates equals the index of the normalizer" can be found?

@GrigorHakobyan I suspect this is an exercise in almost any group theory textbook in the chapter on actions

@GrigorHakobyan You can find proofs in this very website.
